# How to use str_replace to hide beginning of title

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to delete the beginning of a title?

For example, if I want to delete anything that comes behind the "-" including that itself

Example: Bob Billy - Hello Lyrics --> Hello

is it possible?

I'm trying to do this in php so it works for all titles at once, 
all my titles end in lyrics, so i took out lyrics using this 
" ";

But not for advertising purposes I want to edit  all titles on my site, and take out everything behind the "-"
 (Bob billy - hello lyrics - > hello)

Comment: WordPress is not a language. It's software. The underlying language is PHP. I have added the tag so you can receive more help. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'anything that comes behind the "-"'

Comment: For example, all my titles include the "-"

Bob billy - sfssdf Lyrics

How do I get rid of the "Bob Billy" Part, for every title
"Artist Name" - "Song Name" Lyrics --> "Song Name"

Comment: as the others already said why you don't use RegEx `preg_replace` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you just need to find the index of "-" or whatever you want as your starting point (strpos) and use str_replace to replace it and anything before it with an empty string.

Comment: Would you mind telling me how to do so? I'm not very good at things like this

Comment: @user3204897 See the answer below, he has examples

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Bob Billy - Hello Lyrics";
list($artist, $title) = explode("-", $string, 1);
```

Now `$artist = "Bob Billy"` and `$title = "Hello Lyrics"`.

Alternatively, you could use Regular Expressions

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^-]+-(.*) Lyrics/", "$1", $string);
```

Now `$string = "Hello"`.

Comment: The first one, that's that'll effect all posts and replace every title with those words, but what I'd like to do is edit everything so that anything with any title that includes "-" has nothing behind it, include even the -.

Comment: Come again? Could you exemplify?

Comment: I mean, all posts are different, I have thousands of posts, with that code i'd have to I think, create strings for everything, I want to change every single post, and just get rid of everything that is behind the "-", you get what I mean?

Comment: @user2320262 Depending on what `$string` is, this will work for all your songs.

Comment: So i'd be using this then?
$string = preg_replace("/[^-]+-(.*) Lyrics/", "$1", $string);
how would I place that in the php code? 
And in the code for the string, do I replace that well with a "The_title()" php to change it for all titles? I know I sound pretty stupid right now...

Comment: Let's say I have a title, let's forget about bob billy and everything. I just have a full on title with "-" there, how can I simply use a code to get rid of everything behind the - for every single post that all have different title, but the "-" sign in there
(different title - more of title)  -> (more of title), because so far the examples given tell me how to do it with that one single title, and even if i have to change the strings so it can change every post, i'd have to basically add all titles so it works for everything, or is there a string i can use that changes everything..